# PowerDesigner linux alternative

Tags: relational-database, data-modeling, powerdesigner

I need a tool that I can create a phisical schema for my relational database. Something that I create tables, columns and relationships, and the tool generates sql to me.

[PowerDesigner example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy3hq.png)

I've used PowerDesigner for many years in Windows and it has worked good to me. Now I need some similar to use in Arch Linux with gnome. Any suggestion?

oh.. my database is PostgreSQL and I look for something free.

[EDIT] I have tested some alternatives and no one serves me well. SQL Power Architect is discontinued and don't work properly. DBVisualizer is limited in free version. DataModeler don't generate sql how I expect.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend DbVisualizer. If you are limited by the free version you can start a free trial of the Pro version. On their Postgres page they seem to have what you need. [DbVisualizer - PostgreSQL Client](https://www.dbvis.com/database/postgresql/)